# Is doing a getDescribe() on an object subject to FLS security review rules?

Tags: apex, security-review

Will I get flagged in the security review if I return a list of fields on the Contact object (or Account, Contact, Opporunity) to the user by doing this?

```
schemaMap.get('Contact').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In fact, you *need* to use describes to properly enforce FLS, because it's the only way to find out if a field is accessible.

A couple examples:

```
Boolean isContactNameAccessible = SObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.isAccessible();
Boolean isAccountNameAccessible = Account.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Name')
    .getDescribe().isAccessible();
```